# can not find error in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have created two class application, classes are 1. InVoice 2. InVoiceTest, i am importing InVoice class into InVoiceTest here is InVoice Class

```
public class InVoice
   {
    private String name;
     private String description;
    private int quantity;
        private double price;

     public InVoice (String n, String d, int q, double p)
     {
    name=n;
       description=d;
      quantity=q;
    price=p;
    }
    public void set (String n, String d, int q, double p)
   {
   name=n;
      description=d;
      quantity=q;
     price=p;
      }
      public String getname()
     {
   return name;
    }

   public String getdescription()
   {
    return description;
    }
     public int getquantity()
   {
  return quantity;
  }
       public double getprice()
    {
     return price;
   }
  }
```

and this is InVoiceTest class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class InVoiceTest
   {
    public static void main (String [] aa)
   {
  InVoice object=new InVoice();
Scanner obj=new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.print("Enter Item name: ");
String name=obj.nextLine();

  System.out.print("\nEnter Item description: ");
    String description=obj.nextLine();

   System.out.print("\nEnter quantity: ");
    int quantity=obj.nextInt();

  System.out.print("\nEnter price: ");
 double price=obj.nextDouble();

object.set(name,description, quantity, price);
}
```

}

these both classes are in same directory, and i am compiling them through command prompt, and this error is being shown again and again

```
InVoiceTest.class can not find symbol
symbol: constructor InVoice()
location: class InVoice
InVoice object=new InVoice();
```

Comment: `InVoice` does not have a default constructor (`InVoice()`)

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have a constructor the Java compiler will create a no-arguments constructor for you.

As soon as you provide a constructor which has arguments the no-argument constructor does not get created by the compiler.

So if you add a no-arguments constructor to InVoice (like below) it should work.

```
public InVoice() {
}
```

Comment: @ammi at least accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

The other way is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class InVoiceTest
   {
    public static void main (String [] aa)
   {
  InVoice object=new InVoice("abc","efgh",1,1.0);
//Scanner obj=new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.printf("%s %s\n", "The Item name is: ",
                object.getname());
//String name=obj.nextLine();

  System.out.printf("%s %s\n","The Item description is: ", object.getdescription());
    //String description=obj.nextLine();

   System.out.printf("%s %d\n","The quantity is: ",object.getquantity());
    //int quantity=obj.nextInt();

  System.out.printf("%s %s\n","The price is: ",object.getprice());
 //double price=obj.nextDouble();

 // object.set(name,description, quantity, price);
 System.out.printf("\n%s:\n\n%s\n",
            "Updated object", object);

}

}
```